# Як буде з російської "Меня терзают смутные сомнения" (коли сумніваєшся у чомусь)?

Tags: переклад, from-russian

Як буде з російської "меня терзают смутные сомнения" (коли сумніваєшся у чомусь — єдиний мені відомий випадок вживання є у фільмі ["Іван Васильович змінює професію" (1973)](//www.youtube.com/watch?v=5_1MD9t9tU8))? "Мене гризуть непевні сумніви"?

Ось як можна використовувати російську фразу: коли хочеш сказати, що відбувається щось вкрай (або скоріше, не зовсім вкрай) підозріле. Треба намагатися знайти відповідний сталий вираз українською.

Переклади на lingvo: [терзать](http://www.lingvo.ua/uk/Translate/ru-uk/%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C), [смутный](http://www.lingvo.ua/uk/Translate/ru-uk/%D1%81%D0%BC%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9).

Comment: Kosarar, Ви не могли навести приклад ситуації, коли потрібна така фраза? Бо не кожний сталий вираз однієї мови має точний еквівалент в іншій. Але якщо наводити не (лише) фразу-оригінал, а суть, що саме і як саме треба сказати — то шансів знайти більше.

Comment: Іще, прохання: оформлюйте, будь ласка, посилання якось оковирніше.

Comment: Але на `on hold`, по-моєму, модератор поспішив це питання ставити. Бо питання цікаве. Просто **трішки** недооформлене.

Comment: Kosarar, наприклад — чим прямий переклад «мене мучать сумніви» не влаштовує? (Так, без слова «неясные» — але який сенс воно несе? В крайньому разі: «мене мучать **незрозумілі** сумніви» — хоча, мені здається, російська фраза вживається не лише тоді, коли мовець сам не розуміє природу своїх сумнівів, а просто автоматично, тому оте «неясные» не несе ніякого сенсу.)

Comment: @Sasha - Так це ж не сталий вираз, це мем, цитата з фільму «Іван Васильович змінює професію». В кіні так: «Меня терзают смутные сомнения: на Вас точно такая же замшевая импортная куртка, как у Шпака!» І це речення є й в ориґіналі в Булгакова в п’єсі «Іван Васильович», тільки Ґайдай його дещо змінив: «Бунша: Меня терзает смутное сомнение. На вас такой же костюм, как у Шпака!» На жаль, Булгакова українською годі й шукати...

Comment: Можна перекласти як "Мене бентежать невиразні сумніви", але сама оригінальна фраза має ритм - ямб із наголосом на парних складах (меня́ терза́ют сму́тные сомне́нья), тож треба якось змінити переклад щоб і в ньому був ритм, наприклад "Мене́ бенте́жить невира́зний су́мнів".

Comment: @YellowSky, тобто шукається не просто переклад — а саме якийсь (більш-менш схожий) український мем? Чи необов'язково мем — але яким критеріям має відповідати переклад?

Comment: @Sasha - Як на мене, то Artemix трохи вище чудово все сформулював, якби знов відкрили питання (я за це проголосував), то цей його коментар був би чудовою відповіддю.

Comment: @YellowSky, я теж за це проголосував. Але, так би мовити, **авансом**. Тут я (як не дивно!) згоден з bytebuster, що запитання треба доформулювати — не читач має здогадуватись, що треба запитувачу, а це має бути сказано в тексті (най і не відразу); ну і навіщо ті неоковирні лінки без назв — незрозуміло. В мене більше протест викликали раптовість і одноосібність закриття — а не саме закриття.

Comment: "Kosarar, Ви не могли навести приклад ситуації, коли потрібна така фраза?"

Коли сумніваєшся у чомусь, Sasha.

Comment: "це запитання (знову) не містить ні контексту," 

Коли сумніваєшся у чомусь.

-

"ні приблизного перекладу,"

Мене гризуть непевні сумніви.

-

"ні пояснення, чим інформація у наведених джерелах не підходить до ваших потреб. – bytebuster♦ yesterday"

Може й підходить - хотів звернутися до Вас, як Найбільшого Фахівця з цього питання, щоб ви прояснили саме цей момент для мене, недостойного.

Comment: @Kosarar, (1) дуже прошу, додайте, будь ласка, це до самого запитання (кнопкою «edit»). Текст має бути повним, читач має розуміти Вашу мету і що саме шукається, не вчитуючись в коментарі. (2) Якщо просто «коли сумніваєшся у чомусь», то в чому тоді сенс слова «неясные»? Воно несе якийсь додатковий зміст, чи ні? (3) Відповідаючи комусь в коментарях, варто вказувати адресат через @ (он як я Вас на початку цього коментаря). Інакше йому не прийде сповіщення і він може прочитати Ваш коментар запізно.

Comment: @Sasha (1) Це все є у самому запитанні, і було з самого початку. (2) Коли є сумніви, але "неясные". Ніби сумніваєшся, але неясно. Не знаю, як краще пояснити. Івана Васильовича дивилися? (3) Нічого, я почекаю. Але тепер знатиму.

Comment: на lingvo є україномовний інтерфейс ;)

Comment: @Kosarar, дивився, але я не пам'ятаю там такої репліки (я неуважний до таких деталей). Все-таки, я вважаю, що Ви **маєте** пояснити це прямо в тексті питання. Бо інакше виглядає якось так: «перекладіть те, не знаю що, щоби воно при цьому відповідало критеріям, не скажу яким».

Comment: @Sasha, "дивився, але я не пам'ятаю там такої репліки (я неуважний до таких деталей" Якої саме репліки Ви не пам'ятаєте? Подивіться уважніше (так, ПРЯМО в текст питання), може вийде.

Comment: @bytebuster, що ще у моєму поганому запитанні Вам не подобається? Нагадаю, що на попередню Вашу критику я спробував у міру своїх скромних можливостей відповісти:
https://tinyurl.com/l5vngwv

Comment: @Yola, щиро дякую.

Comment: @Kosarar, я мав на увазі, що не пам'ятаю, щоб фраза «меня терзают смутные сомнения» звучала в цьому фільмі (я не кажу, що вона там не звучить — просто не пам'ятаю її там) — тому посилання на фільм не допомагає мені з'ясувати контекст, на жаль.

Comment: @Sasha, це нічого, жодних до Вас претензій. Хоч якось би перекласти - було б непогано.

Comment: @Kosarar, річ у тім, що «просто перекласти», здається, не вписується в тематику цього сайту. Про це [питалося](//area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/22648/146894) ще на етапі узгодження сайту з адміністрацією Stack Exchange. Зверніть увагу на [відповідь Robert Cartaino](//area51.meta.stackexchange.com/a/22652/146894) — це один з адміністраторів самого Stack Exchange. Тобто просто «перекладіть мені цеє» — ні; але щось цікаве: сталий вираз чи конкретні відтінки значень абощо — так.

Comment: "However, some idiomatic expressions can be difficult to express between languages, so those types of finer-point questions are typically well-regarded for a site like this."

А ще є ж момент: не хочеш, не відповідай. Просто.

Comment: @Kosarar, так, і в такому випадку варто пояснити, які саме "fine points" Ви хочете (а не лишити читача здогадуватись). Я, наприклад, чесно не розумію, що саме Ви хочете в цьому випадку («хоч якийсь переклад» — не варіант; «хоч якийсь переклад» є [там](//translate.google.com.ua/#ru/uk/меня+терзают+смутные+сомнения); і створювати питання, НМД, варто лиш в тому випадку, якщо такий «перший-ліпший» переклад Вас не влаштовує, причому пояснивши чим). «А ще є ж момент: не хочеш, не відповідай» — або не подобається, мінусуй (чи голосуй за закриття).

Comment: Так, демократія - це важливо. І розумні модератори - також. Переклад, який Ви навели, має дві вади: (1) там нема "смутные"; (2) зовсім відірвано від архитипового джерела - фільму Гайдая.

Comment: @Kosarar, спробую і я. У питанні взагалі нічого не сказано про те, що ви шукаєте переклад, що має відповідати "фільму Гайдая". Так, як сформульовано "(коли сумніваєшся у чомусь)" достатньо просто перекласти "Я сумніваюся" :) Тому всі просять оновити питання, бо дійсно з самого тексту, без коментарів, наприклад, особисто мені незрозуміло, що вам потрібно. Я російську фразу зрозумів так: "Коли хочеш сказати, що відбувається щось вкрай підозріле" й намагався б знайти відповідний сталий вираз українською. Питання цікаве, мені б дуже хотілося зробити reopen, але його треба розширити.

Comment: @Kyrylo Yatsenko♦, добре, що Ви не заперечуєте, що наведений Sasha переклад не відповідає Вашому баченню фрази як "Коли хочеш сказати, що відбувається щось вкрай підозріле". Мені не обов'язково наполягати саме на фільмі Гайдая, але цієї фрази більше ніде й нема. Тому я й казав з самого початку - будь-який (адекватний) переклад мене (і усіх зацікавлених користувачів цього сайту) може влаштувати. Але з особистої ласки до Вас я повставляю ваше бачення цієї фрази.

Comment: @Kosarar, щоби звернутися до користувача, в його імені не потрібно писати прогалків і знаку «♦». Коли ви пишете `@Ky`, воно Вам далі само підказує можливі варіанти, наприклад, `@KyryloYatsenko`. (А «♦» — це не частина псевдоніму, це ознако того, що користувач — модератор.)

Comment: @KyryloYatsenko, Korasar написав Вам відповідь.

Comment: @Kosarar, по суті, щодо «там нема „смутные“» — в запитанні не сказано, що воно має бути. В такому випадку шукають переклад за змістом, а не щоби було відтворене кожне слово. Крім того, може, це моя вада (мабуть, так), але я не розумію, яку роль там це слово несе — я не розумію, як можливості використання «меня терзают сомнения» відрізняються від можливостей використання «меня терзают смутные сомнения» (чи справді різниця в змісті, чи ритм, як припустив Artemix, чи близькість до фільму, чи щось ще).

Comment: Korasar, під час редагування я помітив, що Ваше посилання (`http://tinyurl.com/mr53ze` → `http://revtwt.com/802805`) не працює, але я його не змінював, бо не зрозумів, яке посилання Ви збиралися вставити.

Comment: Korasar, я повернув свій плюс Вашому питанню, бо так, на мою думку, виглядає значно краще.

Comment: Off-topic: [отут](http://pro-status.com.ua/citaty/308.php) вживається «турбують смутні сумніви» — але очевидно, що сенс українського «[смутний](http://sum.in.ua/s/smutnyj)» зовсім інший, ніж у російського «[смутный](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/1031642)», тому, незважаючи за зовнішню подібність, ці вирази зовсім різні.

Comment: @Sasha, дякую; "смутные сомнения" - непевні, які не до кінця сформувалися. "Смутний" в українській мові інше - це-то мене й бентежить (теж).

Comment: Я голосую за перевідкриття цього запитання завдяки тому, що автор поправив велику кількість попередніх недоліків.

Answer (score 4):

Я не знаю відомого відповідника фрази `меня терзают смутные сомнения`, тому напрошується звичайні фрази `я не впевнений` або `я вагаюсь`.

Однак, коли хочеться сказати, що відбувається щось вкрай (або скоріше, не зовсім вкрай) підозріле, то можна вживати такий вираз:

**Коїться щось кепське/підозріле**

> — Так. Я вам на мапі покажу.
>   — А нащо вам? — поцікавилася Весніла. 
>   **— Кажуть, там щось кепське коїться.** — Кепське? — Щось таке я чула. Щось
>   таке дивне… Мабуть, плітки. Але ж нащо вам?
>
> Ряполова Марія, "Бурецвіт"

Comment: А ще у Подерв'янського (майже цитата): *«Погана мода. Щось кепське коїться у Датському князівстві. Коли я був царем…»* :-)

Answer (score 4):

Воно й не дивно, що ви більше не змогли знайти ніде цієї фрази, бо, здається, вона вперше і з'явилася в фільмі "Іван Васильович міняє професію" та п'єсі "Іван Висильович". Ось, що я знайшов на сайті [Циклопедия](http://cyclowiki.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F_%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82_%D1%81%D0%BC%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F):

> Известное высказывание Ивана Васильевича Бунши в фильме «Иван
>   Васильевич меняет профессию» (восходит к литературному первоисточнику
>   фильма — пьесе Михаила Афанасьевича Булгакова «Иван Васильевич»).

Пізніше люди почали вживати його для вираження того, що вони в чомусь сумніваються. Крім того, частіше ця фраза має дещо жартівливий характер (воно й не дивно, бо фраза ж взята з комедії).

Перш за все, ми можемо її просто перекласти:

Мене мучать сумніви ([Гугл](https://translate.google.com/?hl=uk#view=home&op=translate&sl=ru&tl=uk&text=%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%20%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82%20%D1%81%D0%BC%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)).

Мене мучать [смутні](http://sum.in.ua/s/smutnyj)/тривожні сумніви (дослівний переклад).

Однак, також я і зустрічав в Інтернеті коли люди вживали цю фразу без перекладу, наприклад ось пост одного із користувачів [Фейсбуку](https://www.facebook.com/groups/ukrpereklad/permalink/1114405998595167/):

> "**Меня терзают смутные сомнения**..." Або я чогось не розумію, або
>   Теодор Ретке (Рьотке) поет таки американський (хоч і німецького
>   походження), а вірш його перекладався не з німецької, а з англійської.

І ще одна стаття із сайту [УНІАН](https://www.unian.ua/politics/170825-lyapinu-terzayut-smutnyie-somneniya.html):

> «Зараз створюється коаліція стабільності, і щось «меня терзают смутные
>   сомнения», - пожартувала К.ЛЯПІНА.

І саме тут я б хотів зупинитися і сказати чому не варто перекладати цю фразу. Перш за все, коли ми скажемо "меня терзают смутные сомнения", то в більшості випадках людина (якщо вона бачила фільм, звичайно) зрозуміє звідки ця фраза і вловить цей "жартівливий характер", і саме цей характер ми можемо втратити при перекладі. Тобто я веду до того, що таку фразу перекласти буде досить складно і пошук еквіваленту тут може бути недоречний. Для мене це щось на кшталт фрази "Veni vidi vici", яка є добре відома багатьом людям і її впринципі не потрібно перекладати (проте, врахуйте, що хоч саме в цьому абзаці є мої власні думки, я не намагаюся їх нікому нав'язати).

Однак, я вирішив пошукати чи є в нашій мові якісь еквіваленти. Ось що мені вдалося знайти:

"[Сумнів бере](https://ukrainskamova.com/publ/chinnij_pravopis/leksika/klasifikacija_frazeologizmiv/5-1-0-70)" (однак, пише, що це стилістично-нейтральний фразеологізм). А також знаходимо його в [СУМі](http://sum.in.ua/s/sumniv).

В такому випадку виходить:

"Мене (можливо ще додати прикметник "тривожний/тривожні") сумнів/сумніви бере/беруть"

"[Чи ж пак](https://ycilka.net/slovnyk_fraz_view.php?id=16)" - уживається для вираження сумніву, непевності, нерішучості або іронії. І тут мені здається все буде залежати від контексту і я не зовсім впевнений, що можна цією фразою замінити "Меня терзают смутные сомнения".

Отож, гадаю, що "**сумнів бере**" буде хорошим відповідником.